# ICP 2.1.0 installation fails

Tags: ibm-cloud-private

I am trying to install ICP 2.1.0 on RHEL (x86) and the installation fails with the bellow error:

and failed the installation.

During the cloudant initialization, we saw the bellow error:

> Cloudant error: curl: (7) Failed to connect to cloudantdb port 5984:
>   Operation timed out

This step is failing while initializing the cloudantDB during the installation.

Can you please suggest if anything we missed during our installation or anyway to skip the cloudant initialization during the installation?

We have bellow resources on our VM

Also we have allocated 120GB on "/" and 150 GB on "/var"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend trying the following:

- Clear your failed install, ensure that /opt/ibm and /opt/kubernetes are wiped as these can cause storage issues when retrying.
- Bump your allocated storage up to around 160GB as per [the suggested hardware requirements](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/supported_system_config/hardware_reqs.html).
- When you re-attempt [the installation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSBS6K_2.1.0/installing/install_containers_CE.html), after you've loaded the ICP images into Docker, also load the Cloudant image using `docker pull ibmcom/cloudant-developer` as this will reduce the time needed to intialize it.